# Best approach to predict the days to wait to buy an airline ticket

Tags: machine-learning, predictive-models

I have a dataset with flight price observations collected over 3 months. I am trying to make a model that is able to recommend to a traveler the best time to buy a flight ticket, telling him the days to wait for the price to go down.

For each flight, I have calculated the difference in days between the current day and the day that the price will be the lowest before the flight departs. This would be my target variable, it has the following distribution:

[image]

As you can see most of the values are zeros. What would be the best approach to tackle this problem?

Comment: Keep in mind that this algorithm would work only if people would not use it. If people start using it and change their buying patterns, likely the airlines would change the price strategy and there would be a feedback loop. To fight it, you would need to constantly re-train your model, somehow correcting for the feedback loop, what is a non-trivial problem by itself.

Comment: A good approach to this problem would use more information, especially concerning how much prices change.  It's unlikely anyone would view the optimum strategy as nailing the exact day when prices bottomed out: usually travelers want to keep the *expected price* reasonably low without keeping the risk of not being able to travel fairly low.